# Failing to increment pair count correctly add_pairs Tideman CS50

Tags: c, cs50

Could someone please help me to understand why my code fails the points below? This function is meant to update the pairs array with winning pairs and increment the pair_count variable accordingly. My code for the function is as follows:

```
void add_pairs(void)
{
    float cc = candidate_count;// have to set to float to make sure a float number is given as the result
    float majority = (cc / 2);
    // loop through preferences array using nested loop, find preferences for candidates, assign winner or loser depending on scores, increment pair count for each
    // loop nested for, conditional if preferences[i][j] > candidate_count / 2, winner = i loser =j, pair_count += 1. Add pair to pairs array.
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)// loops through preferences array
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > (majority)) // increments pair count in the event there is a majority for one candidate over another
            {
                pair_count += 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < pair_count; k++) // adds that pair to the pairs array
                {
                    pairs[k].winner = i;
                    pairs[k].loser = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("pc:%i\n", pair_count);
    return;
}
```

This fits into the larger program:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];// if x prefer then the margin is x/voters - x

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j - adjacency matrix
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the check50 results corresponding to the add_pairs code above

:( add_pairs generates correct pair count when no ties

```
add_pairs function did not produce 3 pairs
```

:( add_pairs generates correct pair count when ties exist

```
add_pairs function did not produce 2 pairs
```

:) add_pairs fills pairs array with winning pairs

:) add_pairs does not fill pairs array with losing pairs

If I run the program as ./tideman a s d with 3 voters at the following preferences a, s, d - s, a, d - a, s, d.  my printf statement at the end of the function shows a correct pair_count of 3 yet I still fail as per the points above

Comment: You might consider describing the problem you're trying to solve and put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask this question as folks there are likely more familiar with cs50, but be sure to read through the help pages before asking to be sure your question includes the required information to be on-topic.

Comment: Ok I will post on there, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've added some more detail, is that any better?